# How to generic a function where params are different structs with different properties?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, generic-programming, swift-protocols

Please refer the following code:

```
import UIKit

struct Item {
    var brandId = 1
    var name: String = ""
}
struct Store {
    var areaName = ""
    var name: String = ""
}

let itemArray = [Item(brandId: 1, name: "item1"), Item(brandId: 2, name: "item2"), Item(brandId: 1, name: "item3") ]

let storeArray = [Store(areaName: "hk", name: "store1"), Store(areaName: "bj", name: "store2"), Store(areaName: "hk", name: "store3")]


var intKeys = [Int]()
var groupedItems = [[Item]]()

var stringKeys = [String]()
var groupedStores = [[Store]]()

extension Array {

    func transTo2d() -> [[Element]] {
        let grouped = [[Element]]()

        return grouped
    }

}

itemArray.forEach { (item) in
    let brandId = item.brandId
    if !intKeys.contains(brandId) {
        intKeys.append(brandId)
        var newArray = [Item]()
        newArray.append(item)
        groupedItems.append(newArray)
    } else {
        let index = intKeys.index(of: brandId)!
        groupedItems[index].append(item)
    }
}
```

My final goal is could using `itemArray.transTo2d()` get a 2d array based on item's `brandId`, using `storeArray.transTo2d()` get a 2d array based on store's `areaName`. I don't how to generic the function that trans 1d array to a 2d array based on the key?

Comment: is your ultimate goal is to have a list of items into each store that is created ? if yes why not just do  `struct Store {  var areaName = ""  var name: String = "" var items:[Item] = []  }`. if no could you elaborate more

Comment: What is the relationship between an `Item` and a `Store`? Also, as far as I know there isn't a native way to create a 2D array in Swift. What you are using is an array of array and not a 2D array.

Comment: Nope, ```Store```, ```Items``` do not have any relationships. Just 2 examples of ```struct``` one's key is ```Int``` type, one's key is ```String```. and i got storesArray, and itemsArray, and wanna trans to 2d array based their own key, but share the same transform logic@Lamar

Comment: Yeah, i goal is write a extension method for ```Array```, to transform a array into array of array(sorry i am not clear the difference of ```array of array``` and ```2D array```),  based on their own key. and i wrote a function to do that in the question. but i do not how to generic it to make, ```Store```, it's key is String, to share the function @ebby94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can write a generic extension for an Array where the elements will either be of type `Item` or `Store` since both of them don't share any relation for you to write a common generic method. You can write extensions for `Array` where the elements will be of the mentioned type. You just need to conform both of your structs to the equatable protocol.

```
struct Item {
    var brandId = 1
    var name: String = ""
}

extension Item : Equatable{
    static func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool{
        return lhs.brandId == rhs.brandId
    }
}

struct Store {
    var areaName = ""
    var name: String = ""
}

extension Store : Equatable{
    static func ==(lhs: Store, rhs: Store) -> Bool{
        return lhs.areaName == rhs.areaName
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Store{
    func transform()->[[Store]]{
        var storeArray = self
        var groupedArray = [[Store]]()
        while storeArray.count > 0{
            if let firstElement = storeArray.first{
                groupedArray.append(storeArray.filter{$0.areaName == firstElement.areaName})
                storeArray = storeArray.filter{$0.areaName != firstElement.areaName}
            }
        }
        return groupedArray
    }
}

extension Array where Element == Item{
    func transform()->[[Item]]{
        var itemArray = self
        var groupedArray = [[Item]]()
        while itemArray.count > 0{
            if let firstElement = itemArray.first{
                groupedArray.append(itemArray.filter{$0.brandId == firstElement.brandId})
                itemArray = itemArray.filter{$0.brandId != firstElement.brandId}
            }
        }
        return groupedArray
    }
}
```

Using the transform function

```
let storeArray = [Store(areaName: "hk", name: "store1"), Store(areaName: "bj", name: "store2"), Store(areaName: "hk", name: "store3")]
let itemArray = [Item(brandId: 1, name: "item1"), Item(brandId: 2, name: "item2"), Item(brandId: 1, name: "item3") ]
print(storeArray.transform())
print(itemArray.transform())
```

This will print this output which is what I believe you wanted.

```
[[Store(areaName: "hk", name: "store1"), Store(areaName: "hk", name: "store3")], [Store(areaName: "bj", name: "store2")]]
[[Item(brandId: 1, name: "item1"), Item(brandId: 1, name: "item3")], [Item(brandId: 2, name: "item2")]]
```